# Force a falling block to place in Minecraft 1.16.4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

What is the best way to force place a falling block?  In other words, is there a way to make a falling block place itself in the air?  If so, what is the best way?  I know you could use barriers under the falling block so it lands and places itself, but I was wondering if there is a better way.  I want to prevent a falling block to break when landing on a torch or another block that breaks falling blocks.  To use the barrier method, I would have to copy the block to a different location, place the barrier down, wait a tick, then copy the block back.  I need this to work with automation, and as little commands as possible, so I am hoping there is a method requiring less commands.  I am making a function that runs a lot of commands that will loop multiple times per tick.  More commands = more lag so less commands would be great.  If any of this is unclear or you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: But wouldn't the barrier method update the gravity block and make it fall again anyway? Or is this an NBT edited falling block so it's any normal block?

Comment: @Penguin it's an nbt edited block.  So any block in the game.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try placing a torch on a wall and then on top of the torch you place your gravity-affected block, it should look like this:

```
▊▊<--- Gravity Affected Block
▊/ <--- Torch
▊
```

Try this.

Comment: I need it to work with existing torches.  Some on the ground, some on a wall.